# Download source from Vercel deployment

Tags: github, deployment, output, backup, vercel

A freelancer I hired to build a website has gone silent for the past 2 weeks. I'm not really sure what happenned to him but I can wait anymore, I started doing backups of his work.

I've been trying to download the source code of the last deployment made on Vercel using this package : https://github.com/CalinaCristian/source-from-vercel-deployment

Everything works except I have no idea what is the last step :
Choose OUTPUT_DIRECTORY:
Where you want your deployment source to be placed
Default value: './deployment_source'

I don't know what to enter as the OUTPUT-DIRECTORY
Anyone can help me with this one? What exactly

Thanks!

Comment: ...isn't that where you want the downloaded files to end up? In any case, this is not a programming question. That makes it off topic here (you can read about what's on topic in the [help/on-topic]).